# Adding components with hooks dynamically

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-state

I am adding components to my parent that contain a state hook to change the content in the child. When I hardcode these children components into the parent, everything works as expected. Every time runUpdate executes, test increments by one and the child is rerendered.

```
const [test, setTest] = useState(0);
const runUpdate = () => {
  // run code
  setTest(test + 1);
};

return (
  <>      
    <Parent runUpdate = { runUpdate }>
      <Child index={test}/>
    </Parent>
  </>
)
```

This is the Child

```
import React from 'react'
export default function Child({index}) {
  return (
    <div>Counter: {index}</div>
  )
}
```

However, I need to add these children dynamically. However, using this code breaks the hook, so while I see the child, it never rerenders.

```
const [childComponent, setChildComponent] = useState(null);
const [test, setTest] = useState(0);
const runUpdate = () => {
  // run code
  setTest(test + 1);
};
setChildComponent(
  <Child index={test}/>
);

return (
  <>      
    <Parent runUpdate = { runUpdate }>
      { childComponent }
    </Parent>
  </>
)
```

What is the correct way to add components dynamically while retaining the hook?

Comment: Nokkond's answer below is correct in that you don't store JSX in React state but doesn't clarify *why* and doesn't address the rendering of dynamic content, which brings me to my question... What is the dynamic aspect of the code you are trying to use here? What you have provided doesn't go far enough to make it clear what you are trying to accomplish. Please [edit] to include a more representative [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

**Store Data, Not Components**: Store the data or identifiers needed to construct the child components in the state, not the components themselves.
Use this data to dynamically create components directly in the JSX of your parent component's render method (or function body, for functional components).
Here's a revised version of your code that follows these principles:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

const Parent = ({ children, runUpdate }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={runUpdate}>Update Children</button>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const DynamicParent = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(0);

  const runUpdate = () => {
    // Update state, causing rerender
    setTest(test + 1);
  };

  // Dynamically create the Child component with updated props
  const childComponent = <Child index={test} />;

  return (
    <>      
      <Parent runUpdate={runUpdate}>
        {childComponent}
      </Parent>
    </>
  );
};
```